# What CRM app can show profile pictures big enough for you to see the faces?

Tags: android, crm, contact-manager

I started putting my contacts into Insightly. But when I looked at them on the Android app, the pictures are so microscopic (1/2" or 13mm) that they're useless. This is the case whether I'm looking at a list of contacts or looking at an individual contact's complete profile.

Is there a CRM that displays larger pictures of contacts? Is there another workaround I could use?  I'd like the following features for each contact:

- name, address, phone, email
- websites and social URLs
- a note field, or multiple notes per contact that could be sorted by date
- profile photo that can appear at least 3/4" (19mm) on an Android phone screen, preferably in list view instead of an individual's complete contact page
- tags, which I can filter by later (so I can review all the people in particular networking groups I'm part of, for example)

Comment: Hi. Is the CRM for personal or business use? Also, please clarify what platform you want it to run on, apart from android app. If you are happy with Insightly, you could try getting them to fix the issue...

Comment: @ZZ I do a lot of business networking, so before visiting a networking meetup I like to review the faces & names of everyone I've met there. That's what I'm using the CRM for. In addition to my Android I'd like to be able to view contacts online (on my Windows PC). I'd rather not wait for Insightly to maybe-or-maybe-not improve their app, especially if there's another app that does what I want already!

Comment: Ok, got it. Note that you can just use your Android Phone for that and sync contacts to your Windows PC. I do that for contacts, and keep them off the internet. To sync, I use a free app MyPhoneExplorer which has a Windows desktop app. It can also sync with Outlook. If this helps, can write full answer. The Notes field in Android/Outlook/MyPhoneExplorer is just one field though.

Comment: @ZZ Thanks. I actually just remembered I also want to be able to filter by tags that I apply to contacts! I'm going to add the new requirements to my question.

Comment: No problem. I actually use the Note field in Android contacts for tags too by just entering a tag on a line... Also, you could use the "groups" as tags. Anyway, let's see what others suggest.